# What is a good way to connect a soundboard to a computer?

Tags: audio-recording

I have an [EPM 8](https://adn.harmanpro.com/product_attachments/product_attachments/1985_1422315863/EPM8-Top_original.jpg) mixer by Soundcraft. How could I connect the mixed signal in a stereo format? Is there any best way to minimize latency? Is firewire good to use? I have a Firewire input on my computer. I want to run it through Audacity.
Thanks, Charlie

Answer (score 3):

The EPM8 looks to me like it's an all analog setup. IMHO, the best way to hook this up is with a stereo adapter cable into a decent sound card.

To minimize latency, keep it analog as long as possible,  then have a high quality sound board to handle the A to D conversion.

Comment: And not that by "high quality sound board" that doesn't mean go get a high end sound blaster, it means go get an audio interface card designed to take professional inputs.

Comment: Which is the "best" professional sound interface? Is it better to use Firewire to minimize latency? I want to keep it stereo but don't know how.
Thanks, Charlie

Comment: What is an audio interface that has professional inputs? How would I rig it up?

Answer (score 1):

I use a Edirol UA25 (its about 10 years old now) but that connects via USB 2.0 to my MacPro which connects to my Soundcraft mixer.

I have all my sound kit, Mic, iPhone, etc connected to the mixer and the outputs to the inputs on the Edirol and the outputs on the Edirol to the speakers.

Comment: How would I connect that up to my mixer? Is it stereo, and would it work with firewire? What is your setup? 
Thanks, Charlie

Comment: Devices connect to the inputs. The mono outputs (L&R) of the mixer connect to the Edirol inputs on the front (mono L&R) outputs of the Edirol connect to the monitors (Mono L&R) the Edirol is also connected to the MacPro via USB so all audio is sent to the Edirol via USB and is output to the speakers.

Comment: I could also have all the inputs of the mixer and the outputs from the Edirol connect to the inputs of the mixer and the mono (L&R) output connect to the speakers

Comment: FYI I have powered monitors

Comment: FYI page 40 of the manual is a good starting point to get setup, More info on your setup would be best, What audio interface are you using? do you have powered or passive audio monitors?

Comment: Would I use the XLR outs of the EMP 8 to connect to the ins of the  Edirol UA25?
Thanks for all your help!    :)

Comment: Yes you can do, also the Edirol is an old model there are many newer devices but most audio interfaces have the most basic functions but you want something like this https://www.amazon.co.uk/Behringer-U-PHORIA-UMC202HD-Audio-Interface/dp/B00SAV0VP0/ref=sr_1_6?ie=UTF8&qid=1512673758&sr=8-6&keywords=usb+audio+interface

Comment: I have Klipsch R-14M powered monitors. FYI

Comment: They should be fine. Just need an audio interface to connect them all. Buy a decent make and it will give you a good chance at getting decent sound.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69872/discussion-between-airbuslover-and-adam-mann-pro).

Comment: There is a dedicated 1/4 inch out for monitors on my console. Is there a need for an interface?

Comment: Only if you monitors are powered. I did put some more into the discussion as you started it up.